# Which is faster and more efficient - For loop, MATCH, FIND, etc?

Tags: excel, vba

What I am doing is search some strings one by one in the entire range - like search for "blah1", if found then exit, else search "blah2" in the entire range in the same manner.  "blah's" are searched in one column.

Right now i am just running a For loop code as shown below which so far works ok in my tests...but was wondering if MATCH, FIND or other methods may be faster...any opinion?

```
Sub test()

Dim LR As Long
LR = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If Cells(1, "B") = "" Then
For i = 1 To LR
If Cells(i, "A") = "blah1" Then
Cells(1, "B") = Cells(i, "A").Row
Cells(1, "C") = Cells(i, "A")
Exit For
End If
Next i
End If

If Cells(1, "B") = "" Then
For i = 1 To LR
If Cells(i, "A") = "blah2" Then
Cells(1, "B") = Cells(i, "A").Row
Cells(1, "C") = Cells(i, "A")
Exit For
End If
Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it's funny how you refer to Sheet1 on your first line of code and then suddenly it disapears. Note sheet1 often gives errors, prefer using sheets(1) or sheets("sheet1 or other Name")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Since your code is repeated (for "blah1" and "blah2") I used additional function:

```
Sub test()
    If Sheet1.Cells(1, "B") = "" Then
        If findString("blah1") Then Exit Sub
        If findString("blah2") Then Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

'Function findString returns TRUE if something found and FALSE otherwise
Function findString(searchString As String) As Boolean
    Dim rng As Range, res

    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        res = Application.Match(searchString, rng, 0)
        'Application.Match returns error if nothing found
        findString = Not IsError(res)
        If findString Then
            .Cells(1, "B").Value = rng.Cells(res, 1).Row
            .Cells(1, "C").Value = searchString
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: looks compact & interesting, thanx.  will try and post back.

Comment: @Sandy, please, see my last edit. I've just updated my answer

Comment: yes, it works after the edit.  So MATCH is case insensitive, which actually is good for what I am doing .  I was trying to modify your code to work for `set links=html.getelementsbytagname("a")` instead of `Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)`.  Will MATCH work in this case?

Comment: @Sandy, unfortunately I don't familiar with internet scraping. Btw, about using arrays - my code is already _very_ fast and using arrays (in my code) won't give you any sensible benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably new to Excel Vba, but my limited understanding is that reading from cells is relatively slow. If I were doing this I would read all the values into an array, and carry out the same for loop as you have used, but on the array, rather than cell values.

To confirm, you could use VBAs Timer function to check speed.

Let me know if you'd like more detailed explanations of how to do this.

Comment: appreciate the response.  yes, pls post some info or code on the array method

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can turn a range into an array (and vice versa). Step through this code with the Locals window turned on and watch what happens. You are particularly interested in the ***astrArray*** variable.

```
Sub ChangeArray()
'
    Dim astrArray As Variant
'
'   Dim astrArray
'       that is, with no type specified
'       is exactly equivalent
'
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim strMessage As String
'
    Range("A1").Value = "This"
    Range("A2").Value = "is"
    Range("A3").Value = "only"
    Range("A4").Value = "a"
    Range("A5").Value = "test"
    astrArray = Range("A1:A5")
    For lngIndex = 1 To 5
        strMessage = strMessage & astrArray(lngIndex, 1) & " "
        Select Case lngIndex
            Case 1
                astrArray(lngIndex, 1) = "No,"
            Case 2
                astrArray(lngIndex, 1) = "it's"
            Case 3
                astrArray(lngIndex, 1) = "actually"
            Case 4
                astrArray(lngIndex, 1) = "real"
            Case 5
                astrArray(lngIndex, 1) = "life"
        End Select
    Next lngIndex
    MsgBox strMessage
    Range("A1:A5") = astrArray
End Sub
```

A key requirement: to do this, the variable must be DIMmed Variant!

Another thing to pay attention to: the variable is two-dimensional, even though the range selected is one-dimensional.

Comment: thanx much.  i know some big boys on this forum are great proponents of arrays, but wow this one is really advanced for me. mind showing how this conversion can be used in my code?