# VBA Conditional format cell based on whether value is in list of text

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Sub Japan()

Set MyPlage = Range("A1:R1000")
For Each Cell In MyPlage

    If Cell.Value = "A" Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    If Cell.Value = "B" Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    If Cell.Value = "C" Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    If Cell.Value = "D" Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    If Cell.Value = "E" Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

THis find any cells that have either A, B, C, D, E as the value and then colours the entire row red if so.

Basically, I have hundreds of more values that I want to lookup. I have them stored in another excel file (could just as easily be in a text file). How could I reference them? i.e, if cell value is in this list of text, do this.

Comment: Anyone have a tip? Need this fairly quickly and as a VBA beginner i'm struggling!

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258722/which-is-faster-and-more-efficient-for-loop-match-find-etc?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, I'm really inexperienced so it's confusing to see how my example fits in but thanks for the link!

Comment: Are you asking how you can read the file or just how would you use that data once you had it?

Comment: @cheezsteak both. I need to read the file and then use it

Comment: Reading the file depends on what kind of file it is.  Each type of file could raise an issue.

Comment: I basically have a list of text. It can be stored in any file format (.txt .xls). I want to read that list, and if a cell contains any of the values in that list, then the row must be highlighted red.

Comment: Is this a dynamic list? Would copying the values to your excel method be an option?

Comment: @coni2k yes that would be an option!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a [Set datastructure](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) that contains unique values and you can use an `Exist` method on it.

For example your desired usage is this.

```
Set MySet = LoadRedValueSet(???) ' explain later
Set MyPlage = Range("A1:R1000")
For Each Cell In MyPlage
    If MySet.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next
```

Well too bad `Set` is a reserved keyword and VBA does not provide a Set object.  However, it does provide a `Dictionary` object which can be abused like a Set would be.  [You will need to reference the Scripting Runtime Library to use it first through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure).  The usage would be exactly as stated as above.  But first we need to define `LoadRedValueSet()`

Lets assume that you are able to load whatever file you save these values as in as an Excel worksheet.  I will not be explaining how to open various file types in Excel as there are many answers detailing that in more detail than I can.  But once you have your range of values to add to the set we can add them to the dictionary.

```
Private Function LoadRedValueSet(valueRange As Range) As Dictionary

    Dim result As New Dictionary

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In valueRange.Cells
       result(cell.value) = Nothing
    Next cell

    Set LoadRedValueSet = result

End Function
```

Dictionary are mapping objects that have key->value pairs. The key's are effectively a set, which is what we want.  We don't care about the values and you can pass whatever you want to it.  I used `Nothing`.  If you use the `.Add` method the dictionary will throw an error if your list contains duplicate entries.

Assuming you have implemented some function that loads your file as a worksheet and returns that worksheet.

```
Dim valueSheet As Worksheet
Set valueSheet = LoadSomeFileTypeAsWorksheet("some file path")

Dim valueRange As Range
Set valueRange = valueSheet.??? 'column A or whatever

Dim MyDictAsSet As Dictionary
Set MyDictAsSet = LoadRedValueSet(valueRange)

Set MyPlage = Range("A1:R1000")
For Each Cell In MyPlage
    If MyDictAsSet.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways you could possibly do this but here's my approach. `Application.WorksheetFunction.<function name>` can be used to evaluate worksheet functions within VBA. This means we can use it to run a [Match](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) function. For the sake of a simple example let's assume your values to match are in Column A of a worksheet called Sheet2 (in the same workbook).

```
Dim MyPlage As Range, Cell As Range
Dim result as Variant
Set MyPlage = Range("A1:R1000") '<~~ NOTE: Sheets("<SheetName>").Range("A1:R1000") would be better

For Each Cell in MyPlage
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cell.Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"), 0)
    If Not IsError(result) Then
        Rows(Cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next Cell
```

We only need to know whether or not the `WorksheetFunction.Match` function returned an error: If it didn't then Cell.Value was present in Column A of Sheet2 and we color the row red.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your color value + index data to a new sheet called "Colors" in the following order;

```
Value   ColorIndex
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
E       5
```

And update your method with the following code and update the range based your data;

```
Sub SetColors()

    ' DataCells: The cells that's going to be checked against the color values
    Set DataCells = Range("A1:A15") ' Update this value according to your data cell range

    ' ColorValueCells: The cells that contain the values to be colored
    Set ColorValueCells = Sheets("Colors").Range("A2:A6") ' Update this value according to your color value + index range

    ' Loop through data cells
    For Each DataCell In DataCells

        ' Loop through color value cells
        For Each ColorValueCell In ColorValueCells

            ' Search for a match
            If DataCell.Value = ColorValueCell.Value Then

                ' If there is a match, find the color index
                Set ColorIndexCell = Sheets("Colors").Range("B" & ColorValueCell.Row)

                ' Set data cell's background color with the color index
                DataCell.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndexCell.Value

            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```